# Bad superblocks after partition manager error, any way to solve?

Tags: linux, debian, partition, data-recovery, superblock

Alright so I was using Lubuntu to create a swap partition for my KDE Neon system and I used KDE Partition Manager (it came preinstalled with Lubuntu).

It shrinked the drive in 8GB and sat there for a looong time. I use an SSD by the way but the partition was like 480GB so I assume it had to go through all the 480GB or something.

In the end I got an error (I don't remember what the error was) and now the ext4 KDE Neon partition is "unknown".

I tried using the backup superblocks but all of them give the error "filesystem damaged" or something.... Even testdisk says it can't find anything. How can I recover that data?

What could have happened?

[image: Partition table is a little messy]

After making that 8GB partition **after (position-wise, not time)** the KDE Neon ext4 system partition I tried to resize the KDE neon partition (which has the unknown filetype) but it didn't work because you can't resize unknown filetypes, so it just moved the 8GB partition to **before (position-wise)** the KDE neon partition.

**Oh, here's the order of actions:**

Tried to shrink 8GB of my KDE neon partition > ¹KDE Partition Manager failed, gave an error > KDE neon partition now shows up as "Unknown" file system > Tried to resize the KDE neon partition to it's original size (adding 8GB to it) but moved the 8GB partition to before the KDE neon partition
¹- On Lubuntu because I couldn't modify the KDE neon partition while using KDE Neon.

Comment: Also posted at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372488/how-do-i-recover-my-partition-after-an-error

Comment: Apparently, without knowing which error you had there could be very little help. Only the general suggestions, like "reinstall from scratch and restore from backups", which won't answer to "what happened", but rather suggest "what to do now".

Comment: yeah I don't know what Kparted did. I recovered my files using DMDE on Windows though!

Answer (score 1):

Although I wasn't able to recover my partition, I tried using DMDE in Windows and recovered the files!